# how to create xpath by the following web element?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In my Selenium java code i have to click one button and that button have the following web elements

```
<button class="mantine-Button-filled mantine-Button-root secondary-button event-track mantine-1grzg0q" type="button" data-track="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;sales_invoice_add_item_button&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;create_invoice&quot;}"><div class="mantine-3xbgk5 mantine-Button-inner"><span class="mantine-qo1k2 mantine-Button-label">Add items from database</span></div></button>
<div class="mantine-3xbgk5 mantine-Button-inner"><span class="mantine-qo1k2 mantine-Button-label">Add items from database</span></div>
<span class="mantine-qo1k2 mantine-Button-label">Add items from database</span>
```

But i cannot use @class = 'mantine-qo1k2 mantine-Button-label' because in the same page the same class name i have for another button, so please guide me that how can i take the xpath for these elements

Comment: a) why not give the element an id?  Why not use the browser's devtools (inspect element) to select the xpath?

Comment: IDK  what restriction stopping you to use the devtools or why are you not able to create customize locator but you can try this `//button[contains(., 'Add items from database')]`